# ReactJS Replace Broken Image with a Different Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to replace a broken image with a separate element entirely in reactJS?

My current code uses the `onError()` function to set a broken image's `src`

```
<img src={user.avatar} onError={e => e.target.src = '/static/image.png'} />
```

What I'd like to do is replace it with some text instead. Something like:

```
<img src={user.avatar} onError={() => this.replace() } />

replace function(){
  return <div class='some-class'>Image not found</div> // Would replace the image element
}
```

Note* The `user.avatar` property will always be defined, and I'm not looking to use the `alt` attribute

Comment: Why don't you just use [alt Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp)?

Comment: @awran5 I'm looking to swap the entire element, not just sub it for text

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I might do it for a simple image component. We just change what we return if there was an error.

```
export function UserImageComponent({user}){
  const [isError,setIsError] = useState(false);

  if(isError){
    return <div class='some-class'>Image not found</div> // Would replace the image element
  }

  return <img src={user.avatar} onError={() => this.setIsError(true) } />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this strategy:

```js
class Image extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.fallback = () => {
      this.setState({ failed: true });
    };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.failed) {
      return <div classname='some-class'>Image not found</div>;
    } else {
      return <img src={this.props.src} onError={this.fallback} />;
    }
  }
}

const brokenUrl = 'url.png';
const url = 'https://picsum.photos/536/354';
const app = (
  <div>
    <h2>Broken image:</h2>
    <Image src={brokenUrl} />
    <h2>Working image:</h2>
    <Image src={url} />
  </div>);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```